# VS2010 Add-In Debugging Creates a Shadow Copy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, add-in

I'm trying to debug an add-in for Visual Studio 2010. The add-in references another project within my solution. Upon compilation, I can see that the DLL for the referenced project is successfully built and placed in the add-in's build folder.

When I start debugging, a separate instance of Visual Studio is started, and the add-in appears on the Tools menu in Visual Studio 2010. However, when I select the command for it, I receive an error, stating that my referenced assembly could not be found.

This sounds suspciously like Visual Studio is creating a shadow copy of my plugin, and isn't copying the referenced assembly over with it. Is this the case? If it isn't, what's really going on, and how to I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that VS doesn't automatically load referenced assemblies from the add-in's folder. In my add-ins I subscribe to System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve and return my assembly with System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom.

Comment: Um, wut? Why on earth is this the case? I can only imagine it's a security thing, but if my assembly is signed, why on earth wouldn't it get loaded? Anyway, could you kindly provide some references to materials I can use to research this further? Thanks.

Comment: I was wrong. VS loads referenced assemblies from the add-in's folder.

In your "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Addins\MyAddin1 - For Testing.AddIn" <Assembly> points to bin\MyAddin1.dll. bin is not the directory where referenced assemblies are copied. You need to copy your referenced assembly to bin manually or change the path to e.g. bin\Debug\MyAddin1.dll.